# Invariant Lines with 2D Matrix transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -2\\ 5 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ there aren't any invarient lines because (making equations and equating coefficients)

$$\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}4 & -2\\ 5 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\mx+c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X\\mX+c\end{pmatrix}\end{align}\\\implies5x-mx+2c=-2m^2x-2mc$$

S0 $m\in\mathbb{C}$ and also $c=0$? Other matricies have invariant lines, however I'm unsure if it's possible to have $y=mx+c$ where $c\neq0$ as an invariant line. What would the 2x2 transformation matrix look like for this?

Comment: Are you familiar with eigenvectors and eigenvalues ?

Comment: @Digitallis yes, is there a matrix with eigenvalues/vectors that predict an invariant line that doesn't necessarily pass through the origin?

Comment: I assume you're looking for a matrix which is not the identity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a line pass through $p$ and be parallel to some vector $v$.

If $Ap' = p'$ for all $p'$ on the line (i.e. $A$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue) then

$$ A(p + \lambda v) = p + \mu v \iff  \lambda Av = \mu v$$

It follows that the line is invariant if and only if the $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

If $v$ is a multiple of $p$ then the line passes through the origin.

If $v$ and $p$ are linearly independent then the line does not pass through the origin.

As an example consider the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

which has eigenvalues $2$ and $1$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v = (1,0)$ and $p =(-2,1)$.

The line passing through $(-2,1)$ and parallel to $(1,0)$ is an invariant line which does not pass through the origin.